# Machine config instead of app.config files for console apps

Tags: app-config, configuration-files

Is it possible to use connection strings in a Console app's app.config file in a single machine config file instead? So all console apps on the server can use the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, but that would mean that *any* .NET application could gain access to your database.

I would advise against it, for several reaons:

- A possible security hole.
- Most developers would look for this information in `app.config` not `machine.config`.
- You may end up sharing connection strings that only one or two applications need with all applications.
- You can't limit what applications will be able to use the connection strings.
- You will not be able to simply move the application to another machine, with the `app.config` file and have everything just work (you will also need to import the connection string information to the new `machine.config`).

You really should keep the configuration with the application that uses it.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I shared this with the IT mgr and the team is ok with those risks due to the nature of our business.

Comment: What if it is a common server with some web apps that share a connection string (in machine.config) and you want to add a console app that uses the same shared connection string?

Comment: @Rez.Net - What about it? The same risks above still stand.